# find out font used in terminal emacs

Tags: fonts

`M-x describe-font` shows fonts when run in mac,
but when I run it on iterm2 (emacs -nw), it doesn't give me anything (no output)

`describe-face` says

```
Face: default (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Basic default face.

Defined in ‘/snap/emacs/2129/usr/share/emacs/29.0.92/lisp/faces.el’.


           Family: default
          Foundry: default
            Width: normal
           Height: 1
```

How do I find out which font is being used in my emacs inside terminal?

Comment: open iterm2 settings and check what font it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I find out which font is being used in my emacs inside the terminal?

No, you can’t, unless you write an ELisp function accessing your terminal’s information file.

And if you use Emacs on a remote machine by SSH, the answer is definitely NO.

---

Assuming that you wrote a GUI program, that program can of course set the font itself.

But what if a terminal program?  Say `hello_world.c`.
It just sends some characters to the terminal, and how to render/draw those characters is the terminal’s job, NOT that program.

Thus **there's no need for Emacs to know what font the terminal uses, because Emacs cannot decide which font to be used** (unless you write ELisp code to change some settings of your terminal).